# Hiding the Accessors in af:tree

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm creating af:tree from the pojo using the data control.
The java class has the sub lists to be displayed as the leaf node of the tree.
I'm able to display the tree ,however the accessors,which is nothing but the names of the lists in the java class are also getting displayed in the tree.

I tried hiding the list accessor names by using the following method ,but this hides all the nodes/Leaves in the tree

```
public void checkIfNodeisAccessor(){

 RichTree tree = this.getOrderTree();
    JUCtrlHierNodeBinding rootNode = null;
           if (tree != null) {
               CollectionModel model = (CollectionModel)tree.getValue();
               JUCtrlHierBinding treeBinding =
                   (JUCtrlHierBinding)model.getWrappedData();
               rootNode = treeBinding.getRootNodeBinding();
           }        
     getAllHierarichalRowsCount(rootNode);
       }
```

private void getAllHierarichalRowsCount(JUCtrlHierNodeBinding nodeBinding) {

```
  Boolean val = null;
    if (nodeBinding != null) {
         val  =  nodeBinding.isAccessorFolderNode();

        //Pass the row and get all the child rows
        if (nodeBinding.hasChildren() &&
            nodeBinding.getChildren() != null) {
            int chlidRowsCount = nodeBinding.getChildren().size();


            for (int i = 0; i < chlidRowsCount; i++) {
                JUCtrlHierNodeBinding childNodeBinding =
                    (JUCtrlHierNodeBinding)nodeBinding.getChildren().get(i);
                   val = childNodeBinding.isAccessorFolderNode();
              //   String val =  nodeBinding.getLabel();
              setRenderValue(!val);

                getAllHierarichalRowsCount(childNodeBinding);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is my JSPX code :

```
<af:tree value="#{bindings.orderList1.treeModel}" var="node"
                       selectionListener="#{bindings.orderList1.treeModel.makeCurrent}"
                       rowSelection="single" id="t2" clientComponent="true"
                       binding="#{backingBeanScope.PortalBean.orderTree}">
              <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
                <af:group id="g1">
                  <af:commandLink text="#{node}" id="cl1"
                                  actionListener="{backingbeanscope.portalbean.fetchchildnodes}"
                                  clientComponent="true"
                                  rendered="#{backingBeanScope.PortalBean.renderValue}"/>
                </af:group>
              </f:facet>
                </af:tree>
```

Can Anyone provide any pointers to hiding the Accessor names in the UI